# Newly installed gem not loading in RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I am having some issues getting `Machinist` and `Sham` working for my new rails project. In the past I've used `Factory-girl`.

I've got `rvm` installed and I installed machinist by adding it to my gemfile.

When I run rake i get the following error...

```
/Users/liamnorton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- sham (LoadError)
```

Which is caused by the line at the top of my blueprints.rb file

```
require 'sham'
```

Can someone please help me get this working. I've had issues with RVM in the past and don't want to be imploding and rebuilding if I don't have to!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well surprise surprise, including the line `gem 'sham'` in my `gemfile` worked!

I thought that Sham was dependent on Machinist, and therefore would be install when running `bundle install` but no. Machinist 2 wipes it's hands clean.